# Hibernate não encontra hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse

.
Na hora de indicar para o Hibernate o arquivo de configuração, já tentei caminho relativo errado antes ".cgf) : (../../main/resources/hibernate.cgf.xml). Mas agora corrigi, o caminho absoluto e Hibernate não atualiza, continua procurando como se eu tivesse passado o caminho relativo errado...

Vejam a abaixo a classe de configuração onde eu indico o .cfg e o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: hibernate. **cgf** .xml?

Comment: Digitei errado. .cfg.xml

Comment: Não erdade não digitei errado não. Está escrito assim na mensagem de erro do Hibernate, olha.

Comment: Tem certeza que a mensagem não está simplesmente mostrando o nome digitado por você?

Comment: Isso pode ser o que eu digitei antes, Mas eu corrigi, salvei, fechei e abri o Eclipse, e continua acusando aquela digitação errada anterios. Olha o que eu digitei no código acima.

Comment: Entendi. Estranho que o nome errado persista na mensagem de erro.

Comment: Até reiniciei o computador e não adiantou. Não existe outro lugar onde eu passo o.cfg ...

Comment: Você já tentou apenas `configuration.configure()`? A Hibernate vai encontrar o cfg da sua aplicação. Se precisa informar um arquivo com caminho absoluto, a resposta está [nesse outro post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063330/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-location)

Comment: Tentei agora, nada muda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura do seu projeto no Eclipse está um pouco estranha. Considerando que é um projeto Java com Maven e ele foi importado como projeto Maven, deveria estar assim a sua árvore:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não está nessa estrutura, o plugin do Maven não está colocando o conteúdo de `src/main/resources` no classpath.

Para corrigir a estrutura, clique com o botão direito no seu projeto e execute "Maven/Update Project". Uma vez isso corrigido, use apenas `configuration.configure()` e a Hibernate vai encontrar o seu arquivo cfg.